# Inject parent into child class with Ninject

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

Let's say I have the following code where a dependency needs a reference to the parent.

```
public class Parent: IParent
{
    private readonly IChild child;
    public Parent()
    {
        this.child = new Child(this);
    }
}

public class Child
{
    private readonly IParent parent;
    public Child(IParent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use ICO with Ninject to refactor this code to inject a IChild instance, which itself takes a reference to parent

```
public class Parent: IParent
{
    private readonly IChild child;
    public Parent(IChild child)
    {
        this.child = child;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to tell nancy to always use the current instance to resolve the dependency.

Obviously I could use a factory pattern, in fact that's what I do atm with [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory).

```
public class Parent: IParent
{
    private readonly IChild child;
    public Parent(Func<IParent, IChild> childFactory)
    {
        this.child = childFactory(this);
    }
}
```

But I am wondering if I could refactor this to avoid the factory.

Comment: Why does `Child` need a reference to its parent? Such circular dependencies can, IME, always be avoided, and the resulting code will be easier to use and maintain.

Comment: I do not agree. There are good reasons and use cases to have a child reference it parents and a parent referencing its child(s). Take the Windows Forms `control.Controls[0].Control` or `xDocument.Element("SomeElement").Parent` as a reference. Also, the desired approach to configure Ninject to use a plain `IChild` implementation instead of a factory, would eliminate the requirement to have a constructor which takes a parent as an argument, which is in fact implementation specific. So I see nothing wrong with my approach.

Comment: I don't think that *"Windows Forms does it that way"* is an argument that something is well-designed :) The mere fact that you're having trouble with the design related to NInject is a tautological indication that the design is causing you trouble.